# Scala functional pattern computation state

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, functional-programming

I'm attempting to write a small compiler for a mini language called minijava,
in order to gain insight in compiler construction and functional programming.
My current implementation is in Scala, a language which I'm also just starting to learn.

```
sealed class Record()

case object Usage extends Record
case class Declaration(
    definition: Term,
    typ: Type
) extends Record

class Scope(
val parent: Option[ Scope ],
val scopes: List[ Namespace ],

// represents the actual (local) symbol-table
val symbols: Map[ (Namespace, String), Record ] = new HashMap()
) extends Immutable {

def add( ns: Namespace, id: String, record: Record ): Scope =
    new Scope(parent, scopes, symbols + Tuple2((ns, id), record ))

def enter_scope(scopes: List[ Namespace ]) = new Scope( Some(this), scopes )
def leave_scope() = parent
}
```

Now I can construct a symbol table using this class by going over the AST, and constructing a tree of scopes. This can be done nicely using pattern matching, and functional programming in scala makes sense this way.

However, I need to keep track of the scope that an AST node belongs to in order to make this thing useful... 
So I'd like to somehow wrap this thing in order to build a hashmap of nodes to scopes everytime I add a declaration.

I've considered many patterns, but I can't find a way to do this that is:

- functional
- without mutable state
- nice (i.e. does not make me write stuff feels redundant)

Can anyone come up with something nice?

Comment: I highly recommend you to take a [Programming Languages course by Dan Grossman](https://www.coursera.org/course/proglang). During the course you will construct your mini language in some of the existing langs and using different approaches. One of the languages reminds Scala a lot and it is actually Scala ancestor and influencer: [SML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML).

Comment: I'm currently in 2 compiler construction classes. This question is not  about compiler construction, it is on only the context of the code. But thank you anyway.

Comment: The *Purely Functional State* chapter from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) describes a method for handling state that meets your requirements. Unfortunately, it takes a full chapter written by FP experts to explain! The end result is a new type that describes state transactions.

Comment: Thank you. I hope to take a look at that soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Bound for Scala](https://github.com/runarorama/scala-bound). It is a purely functional library for constructing languages with scoped binders. Instead of a map from symbols to scopes, in which case you would have to have a source of fresh names for your symbols, *Bound* lets you use "locally nameless" terms, and does all of the work of entering, exiting, and traversing, and substituting into scopes for you.

The core of the library is the data type `Scope[B,F[_],A]`, where `F` is your expression language, `B` is a placeholder for bound variables and `A` is a placeholder for free variables. This wraps a value of (essentially) type `F[Either[B, F[A]]]`.

To demonstrate how this works, the binding of a single variable in your language could be represented by something like a lambda term:

```
trait Exp[A]
...
case class Variable[A](a: A) extends Exp[A]
case class Lambda[A](e: Scope[Unit, Exp, A]) extends Exp[A]
```

The body of the lambda is then an `Exp`, and when you hit a `Variable`, it is going to be either the bound variable of type `Unit`, or a free variable, in which case it will be another `Exp[A]`.

The source code for the [Ermine programming language](https://github.com/ermine-language/ermine-scala-core/blob/master/src/main/scala/ermine/syntax/Core.scala) is a good reference for how this library is used in practice.

Comment: Thank you for this reference. I'll accept your answer because it gives me enough material to figure this out.

Another source that I expect much of is this one: http://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/.
I've seen some glimpses of a symbol table in there.